# Neural architectures: data-informed automatic design

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning

The recent progress in neural networks is summarized by a sequence of novel architectures characterized mainly by its growing design complexity. From LeNet5 (1994) to AlexNet (2012), to Overfeat (2013) and GoogleLeNet/Inception (2014) and so on...

Is there any attempt to let the machine decide/design which architecture to be used depending on the data?

Answer (score 12):

You may also want to look at the  literature on [neuro-evolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuroevolution). Examples:

- Zaremba, Wojciech. Ilya Sutskever. Rafal Jozefowicz "[An empirical exploration of recurrent network architectures.](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=9021528542952156548&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22)" (2015): used evolutionary computation to find optimal RNN structures.
- Franck Dernoncourt. "[The medial Reticular Formation: a neural substrate for action selection? An evaluation via evolutionary computation.](http://www.francky.me/doc/mrf2011-HEC-ISIR-ENS_en.pdf)". Master's Thesis. École Normale
  Supérieure Ulm. 2011.
- Bayer, Justin, Daan Wierstra, Julian Togelius, and Jürgen Schmidhuber. "[Evolving memory cell structures for sequence learning.](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=14945304742464379854&hl=en&as_sdt=0,22)" In International Conference on Artificial Neural Networks, pp. 755-764. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2009.: used evolutionary computation to find optimal RNN structures.

Reinforcement learning:

- Pham, Hieu, Melody Y. Guan, Barret Zoph, Quoc V. Le, and Jeff Dean. "Efficient Neural Architecture Search via Parameter Sharing." arXiv preprint arXiv:1802.03268 (2018). https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.03268.pdf
- Zoph, Barret and Le, Quoc V. Neural architecture search
  with reinforcement learning. In ICLR, 2017. https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.01578
- Jose M Alvarez, Mathieu Salzmann. Learning the Number of Neurons in Deep Networks. NIPS 2016. https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.06321
- Bowen Baker, Otkrist Gupta, Nikhil Naik, Ramesh Raskar. Designing Neural Network Architectures using Reinforcement Learning. https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.02167
- Barret Zoph, Quoc V. Le. Neural Architecture Search with Reinforcement Learning. https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.01578

Miscellaneous:

- Marcin Andrychowicz, Misha Denil, Sergio Gomez, Matthew W. Hoffman, David Pfau, Tom Schaul, Brendan Shillingford, Nando de Freitas. Learning to learn by gradient descent by gradient descent. https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.04474
- Franck Dernoncourt, Ji Young Lee [Optimizing Neural Network Hyperparameters with Gaussian Processes for Dialog Act Classification](http://arxiv.org/abs/1609.08703), IEEE SLT 2016.
- Cortes, Corinna, Xavi Gonzalvo, Vitaly Kuznetsov, Mehryar Mohri, and Scott Yang. "AdaNet: Adaptive Structural Learning of Artificial Neural Networks." arXiv preprint arXiv:1607.01097 (2016). https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.01097 : Approach that learns both the structure of the network as well as its weights.

Answer (score 5):

It seems research is moving towards such direction:

- Miconi, Thomas. "[Neural networks with differentiable structure.](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.06216)", arXiv (2016): the author introduce the concept of differentiable network structure to include it in the objective function.

Answer (score 0):

Google's [AutoML](https://research.googleblog.com/2017/05/using-machine-learning-to-explore.html) is one such example. It was successfully applied on the ImageNet dataset, resulting [NASNet](https://research.googleblog.com/2017/11/automl-for-large-scale-image.html), which as of this writing, has surpassed all other models in terms of accuracy. The main paper is here:

[Learning Transferable Architectures for Scalable Image Recognition -- Zoph, et. al.](https://research.googleblog.com/2017/11/automl-for-large-scale-image.html)